# jQuery Pause / Resume animate

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

This ain't working for me...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#h .a').animate({
        top:'-=80px'
    },90,'linear');

    $('#h .au,#h .di').animate({
        left:'-=80px'
    },50000000,'linear');

    $('#h .r').animate({
        left:'-=80px'
    },250,'linear');

    $("#h").animate('pause'); //pausing it at the start
    //resume pause switch
    $("#h").mouseover(function(){
      $(this).animate('resume');
    }).mouseout(function(){
      $(this).animate('pause');
    });

});
```

Comment: Jquery animate doesn't have pause/resume functionality you would use plugin or write it yourself to do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out the demo here: http://api.jquery.com/clearQueue/

Looks like exactly the sort of thing you're trying to do.

Answer (score 11):

try this one for pause and resume: [jQuery Pause / Resume animation plugin](http://tobia.github.io/Pause/)

also we `$(this).stop()` can pause animate but no chance to resume!

other mistake is this one: `top:'-=80px'`

first try to get current position like this then add position to it:

```
_top = $(this).offset().top;

$('#h .a').animate({
    top:_top-80
},90,'linear')
```

Answer (score 2):

Check the plugin: Fxqueues

https://github.com/lucianopanaro/jQuery-FxQueues

It supports both pause and resume (without clearing the queue) and adds the idea of Scopes.  Scopes are great for chaining animations across multiple objects.

I haven't found a version of Fxqueus for the current version of Jquery, but have used it successfully with older Jquery versions.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to look into using the `.stop()` function for this, as it'll stop any animations on a jQuery element.

http://api.jquery.com/stop/

Answer (score 1):

Use [queue()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.queue/) and [dequeue()](http://api.jquery.com/dequeue/) functions. Here's an example taken directly from jQuery documentation.

### Check working example at http://jsfiddle.net/j4SNS/

Comment: if you click stop/start when square moves from right to left, it will shift starting point :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<style type="text/css">
.scroll {
width:100%;
overflow:hidden;
position:relative;
}
 
.scrollingtext {
white-space:nowrap;
position:absolute;
}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.scrollingtext').bind('marquee', function () {
            marqueeFunction($(this), 'START');
        }).trigger('marquee');

        $('.scrollingtext').mouseover(function () {
            $(this).stop();
        });
        $('.scrollingtext').mouseout(function () {
            marqueeFunction($(this), 'RESUME');
        });
    });

    function marqueeFunction(ob, type) {
        // ========== HOROZONTAL ==========
        //                var tw = ob.width();
        //                var ww = ob.parent().width();
        //                if (type == 'START')
        //                    ob.css({ right: -tw });
        //                ob.animate({ right: ww }, 20000, 'linear', function () {
        //                    ob.trigger('marqueeX');
        //                });
        // ========== VERTICAL ==========
        var th = ob.height();
        var hh = ob.parent().height();

        if (type == 'START')
            ob.css({ bottom: -th });
        ob.animate({ bottom: hh }, 20000, 'linear', function () {
            ob.trigger('marquee');
        });
    }
</script>

<div class="scroll">
    <div class="scrollingtext">Some HTML to scroll as a marquee</div>
</div>
```