# OnebyOne.js script support

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, user-experience

Hello i have this script but i want to add inside it when i'm hovering over it stops the animation and when i'm out it should complete the animation normally.it

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/onebyone/jquery.onebyone.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"> 
         $(document).ready(function() {     
           $('#banner').oneByOne({
                className: 'oneByOne1', // the wrapper's name
                easeType: 'fadeInDown', //'fadeInLeft',  // the ease animation style
                width: 580,  // width of the slider
                height: 200, // height of the slider
                delay: 300,  // the delay of the touch/drag tween
                tolerance: 0.25, // the tolerance of the touch/drag  
                enableDrag: true,  // enable or disable the drag function by mouse
                showArrow: true,  // display the previous/next arrow or not
                showButton: false,  // display the circle buttons or not
                slideShow: true,  // auto play the slider or not
                slideShowDelay: 5000 // the delay millisecond of the slidershow
            });
         });
        </script>
```

Comment: This question has some resources about pausing and subsequently resuming animations in jQuery, which may be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5586068/jquery-pause-resume-animate I would also take a look at the `.hover` method.

Answer (score 0):

On [the OneByOne plugin homepage](http://codecanyon.net/item/jquery-onebyone-slider-plugin/684613) there is a clear notice:

> **Like to pause the slideshow when mouse hover?**
>   Please drop me a line via my profile page’s contact form. I can send you the update source.

I suggest you do that.